# Angular momentum in Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

How to calculate the angular momentum of a particle in  a cylindrical coordinates system

$$x_1 = r \cos{\theta}$$
$$x_2 = r \sin{\theta}$$
$$x_3 = z$$

Thanks.

Comment: @Peter I'm still unsure how do i calculate the angular momentum. Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: if i'm not wrong its: Angular Momentum (L) = r x p (where r being the position of the vector, p is the linear momentum)

Comment: In this case, it should be something like this.. $L^2 = L_{x_1}^2 + L_{x_2}^2 +L_{x_3}^2 $ Well.. thats what I'm trying to do

Comment: It seems that we do not need volume integrals here, right ?

Comment: yeah.. i dont think we need volume integrals... I think its more like partial differentiation

Comment: Maybe, the point is to calculate $r$ and $p$ in cylinder coordinates. In which form are $r$ and $p$ given ?

Comment: yeah.. may be.. still not sure though

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are seeking the infinitesimal deformation operators generating rotations, as in quantum mechanics, so, then,  $\vec{p}\sim \nabla$.

In that case, since 
$$
\vec{R}= z \hat z + r \hat r ,\\
\nabla = \hat z \partial_z + \hat r \partial_r + \hat \theta \frac{1}{r} \partial _\theta,
$$

$$
\vec L = \vec{R} \times \nabla = (z \hat z + r \hat r ) \times
\left ( \hat z \partial_z + \hat r \partial_r + \hat \theta \frac{1}{r} \partial _\theta \right ) \\
= \hat z \partial_\theta- \hat r \frac{z}{r} \partial_\theta +\hat \theta (z\partial_r -r\partial_z).
$$ 
Confirm by limiting cases *z=0*, *θ=0*, etc.